# Fazer truncate ignorando a foreing key

Tags: sql

> Cannot truncate table 'ARITREINAMENTO.glo.tbEndereco' because it is
>   being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Já foi executado truncate na tabela agência que referencia o endereço
ou seja, existe na tabela apenas endereços não referenciados por nenhuma outra tabela

Quero fazer `truncate` nas duas para reiniciar os registros e não haver inconsistências (Agências sem endereços e nem endereços sem agências)

Comment: Poderia postar na pergunta o SQL que você está executando?

Comment: é um comando simples
Truncate tbEndereco

Comment: Resolvi excluindo todos os registros da tabela e mudando o valor do auto increment para 1

Comment: Show, coloque como Resposta da pergunta os comandos executados para resolver seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A alternativa que encontrei foi excluir todos os registros da tabela e reiniciar o auto_increment

```
delete from tbEndereco where id < maxID+1
DBCC CHECKIDENT (tbEndereco, RESEED, 0)
```

Obs: o delete só funcionou por que nenhum registro era referenciado por outra tabela

---

.